# Using Microsoft Access, need to pull attachments from Outlook emails of a different account

Tags: vba, outlook

I have working code below to extract attachments from my own Outlook email account, however I need to do it for a different account that is setup as a default reply email box for an automated process.

I'm not entirely sure how to tell the code below to check for that mailbox instead of my own.  I've tried different variations of setting the Inbox variable, but none of them have worked thus far.  This is done within Access 2013.

```
Private Sub GetAttachments()

    Dim ns As Namespace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim FileName As String

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, _
                "Nothing Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each Item In Inbox.Items
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            If Atmt.Type = 1 And InStr(Atmt, "xlsx") > 0 Then
                FileName = "C:\attachments\" & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
            End If
        Next Atmt
    Next Item

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set Inbox = ns.Folders("MailboxName").Folders("Inbox")
```

Comment: I actually just figured this out myself as well; the problem was that I was trying to use the email address or AD name and not the literal name of the mailbox (two words with a space and all that).  Will mark as answer though; thank you for your reply.

Comment: This code assumes the mailbox is already opened in the current profile and the Inbox is actually called "Inbox" (which is not true in other languages).

Answer (score 0):

Use Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder

```
Set recip = ns.CreateRecipient("other mailbox owner")
recip.Resolve
Set Inbox = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, olFolderInbox)
```