# Retrieving shared folders in cached mode

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following code:

```
Set theInbox = GetFolder("SHARED MAILBOX NAME\Inbox")
Set theSub = theInbox.Folders("Subfolder Name Here")
Set theFolder = theSub.Folders("Another Subfolder Name")
Item.Move theFolder
```

This is a Shared Mailbox which I use in Cached Mode. Sometimes "theSub" fails to retrieve the Subfolder.

If I uncheck the Download Shared Folders option, it works properly, however, Outlook is painfully slow.

How can I retrieve the folders when using cached mode?

Comment: Try this setup https://stackoverflow.com/a/34871809/4539709

Comment: It appears non-cached is necessary when there are shared folders. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49602063 "Keep in mind that by default Outlook caches shared folders in the primary mailbox's OST file. Subfolders are not cached. Try to disable the shared folder caching in the Exchange account properties dialog."